# Is there anything I might miss starting out playing Ico?

Tags: ico

I have just started playing Ico and there is no help at the beginning, you're just supposed to figure out what to do. Which I like, its just I want to know if there's anything I can miss at the beginning of the game?

Comment: Also, do I just run around holding some chicks hand beating up shadows with a stick the whole game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's very little that's missable in Ico.  There's one secret area that I'm aware of where you find the best weapon in the game, but there's only 3 weapons total, and the combat is not particularly challenging even without it.

The game is primarily focused on solving environmental puzzles and protecting the princess.  There is very little dialog, and in most releases what dialog there is isn't in English, at least on the first playthrough.  There's also very little story progression through most of it.

Comment: I thought as much. In your opinion was it worth playing?

Comment: @user1016253, it's an artistic piece, and a classic game.  It's certainly not for everyone, however.

Comment: I feel I owe it a try. No point buying a game and not playing it right?

Comment: I feel like it's strongly worth playing.  It's awfully tedious at times but it's worth it when you get to the end.  (Also, the last 30 minutes or so are frankly TOTALLY worth it.)